# Flyway - are there debug levels?

Tags: flyway

On every migration, I don't want to list all the files that are Flyway-readable, which is done twice in two blocks (with hundreds of files, this is too much of unnecessary reading):

```
...(first block, before doing anything, flyway scans the directory and subdirectories)
...(part one: "Found filesystem resource:"    hundreds of times)
[DEBUG] Found filesystem resource: sql/Migrations/Released/Release_5.2/V05_02_00_13__#########.sql
...(immediately after)
...(part two: "Filtering out resource:"       hundreds of times)
[DEBUG] Filtering out resource: sql/Migrations/Released/Release_5.2/V05_02_00_13__#########.sql (filename: V05_02_00_13__#########.sql)
...
...(real migration actions)
...
...(second block, after ALL things done
...(part one: "Found filesystem resource:"    hundreds of times)
...(part two: "Filtering out resource:"       hundreds of times)
...
```

I would like to have few debug levels, so that the listing of files would appear on deepest/highest debug level, so that I don't see it every time. I don't need it.

A flag/variable would be fine. What do you say? :-)

Comment: Feel free to make an issue on the Flyway repo: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues

Comment: @Mikiel thanks. raised here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2668

Answer (score 1):

The 
`[DEBUG] Found filesystem resource`
and
`[DEBUG] Filtering out resource`
messages are only printed when flyway is run with the -X parameter
`flyway migrate -X`

If you run it without the -X, you will only get the actual migration actions printed out.

Comment: I know about -X, that's how I see those messages :-) I want to see debug information, but not to list all the files